# Insert on duplicate key update always updates all values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to update a row or insert a new one if it exists. If there's an UPDATE I just like to update the "updated" column with the current timestamp otherwise "added" AND "updated" get the same value (timestamp)

```
//1385982893 is from PHP with time() cause it's needed elsewhere too

INSERT INTO table (id, code, added, updated) VALUES (236, 'abcdefghi', 1385982893, 1385982893)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
id = values(id), code = values(code), added = values(added),updated = 1385982893
```

ID is the primary key. code is UNIQUE

The problem is that "added" always gets updated with the current timestamp (like updated)

Comment: Please rephraze, this is not a clear question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then do not set added in Update

```
INSERT INTO table (id, code, added, updated) VALUES (236, 'abcdefghi', 1385982893, 1385982893)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
id = values(id), code = values(code), updated = 1385982893
```

Answer (score 4):

You just need to to remove the `added = values(added)` and it won't get updated:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, code, added, updated) VALUES (236, 'abcdefghi', 1385982893, 1385982893)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
id = values(id), code = values(code),updated = 1385982893
```

Comment: Thanks, I have to honored the first commenter though